# How do you pull one word from a .txt using StringTokenizer?

Tags: java

I've been trying to get my program to pull one word out at time from my .txt file but I have to do it with a tokenizer but i can't seem to get it right.

```
public void getWord(){
    ASCIIDataFile in=new ASCIIDataFile("JavaReservedWords.txt");    
    while (in.isEOF()) {
        String word = in.readString();
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(word);

        while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
        System.out.println(st.nextToken());
    }
    in.close();
}
```

I don't know you to limit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I didn't have access to the ASCIIDataFile so I implemented it with a
>   BufferedReader:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Main {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    StringTokenizer tokenizer;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Main main = new Main();
        System.out.println(main.getWord());
        System.out.println(main.getWord());
        System.out.println(main.getWord());
    }

    public Main(){
        BufferedReader reader; // replace with your ASCIIDataFile

        try {

            // additionally update this with your ASCIIDataFile as needed
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("your-file-here"));
            String read;

            while((read = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(read);
                sb.append(","); // or whatever delimiter you want
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        tokenizer = create();
    }

    public String getWord(){

        if (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            return tokenizer.nextToken();
        }
        else{
            return null; // or throw an exception
        }
    }

    public void reset(){
        tokenizer = create();  // allows to interate through tokens again
    }

    private StringTokenizer create(){
        return new StringTokenizer(sb.toString(), ",");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the delimiter being used in the text file?   Also, you should change

```
while(in.isEOF())
```

to

```
while(!in.isEOF())
```

Comment: In order to tell where one word ends and another begins, your file must have a delimiter.  A delimiter is typically a tab character, space, comma, semicolon, etc.  In a file where a comma is used as a delimiter for example, you would have

word1,word2,word3,word4...

The StringTokenizer uses the delimiter to figure out where to split a string into tokens..

Answer (score 0):

do you want to print exactly one word? Can't understand what do you expect. 
If you want to limit output as the very first word from every row then you should do

```
if (st.hasMoreTokens())
    System.out.println(st.nextToken());
```

Comment: Im tryring to get one word at a time from the file I have.

Comment: Separate the words with a space (" ")

Answer (score 0):

This does as you specify. It opens a file and iterates through each word in each line.

```
import  java.io.File;
import  java.io.IOException;
import  java.util.regex.Matcher;
import  java.util.regex.Pattern;
import  org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import  org.apache.commons.io.LineIterator;

/**
   <P>{@code java FileWordIteratorXmpl regex_to_word_iterate.txt}</P>
 **/
public class FileWordIteratorXmpl  {
   public static final void main(String[] as_1RqdTxtFilePath)  {
      LineIterator li = null;
      try  {
         li = FileUtils.lineIterator(new File(as_1RqdTxtFilePath[0])); //Throws npx if null
      }  catch(IOException iox)  {
         throw  new RuntimeException("Attempting to open \"" + as_1RqdTxtFilePath[0] + "\"", iox);
      }  catch(RuntimeException rtx)  {
         throw  new RuntimeException("One required parameter: The path to the text file.", rtx);
      }

      //Dummy search string (""), so it can be reused (reset)
      Matcher mWord = Pattern.compile("\\b\\w+\\b").matcher("");

      while(li.hasNext())  {
         String sLine = li.next();
         mWord.reset(sLine);

         while(mWord.find())  {
            System.out.println(mWord.group());
         }
      }

   }
}
```

Using this file:

```
Hello there
Hello1 there1
Hello2 there2
Hello3 there3
Hello4 there4
Hello5 there5
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code\]java FileWordIteratorXmpl C:\java_code\text_to_word_iterate.txt
Hello
there
Hello1
there1
Hello2
there2
Hello3
there3
Hello4
there4
Hello5
there5
```